# Application size got very big after install ngmap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing android application using cordova and ionic framework. I want to show map inside my application. After some research I got result that ionic support [angular map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps). After install it using bower and add the script to my application, i build my application. Before install ngMap, my application size is 3++ MB, after install ngMap, it's size got 7++ MB. Is this normal? or i miss something? Or are there any other to include google maps to my ionic application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower install ngMap includes example and docs too. if you wont use it, you can delete the app, test app, and all other file. You just need ng-map.min.js for your application. This file is in build/scripts folder